# Join On Indexed Value + 1 Joins Incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to join two data frames on which one has a column created from doing a row/index count.

My first df with a counter on it was created from another method (not index function) that looks like

```
THING   INDEX
  B       1
  B       2
  B       3
```

My second df has an index created using

`df2['INDEX_RAW'] = df2.reset_index().index`

`df2['INDEX'] = df2['INDEX_RAW']  + 1`

So my df2 looks like

```
ITEM   INDEX_RAW  INDEX
 A       0          1
 A       1          2
 A       2          3
```

When I run `df3 = df.join(df2, on = 'INDEX', how = 'left', lsuffix = '1')` , I end up with it somehow incrementing the index another +1 on df2 and not joining properly for the last row.

```
THING   INDEX1   ITEM   INDEX_RAW   INDEX
B          1      A          1        2
B          2      A          2        3
B          3      NaN        NaN      NaN
```

Comment: according to the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) for the parameter `on`, it says `Column ... in the caller to join on the index in other` so it means by specifying this parameter, you will join the column INDEX from `df` to the index (and not the column of the same name) of `df2`, and that creates the "shift" you see in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `on` argument just specifies the column in `df` to join, it's always joined with `df2`'s index column (which is `INDEX_RAW`), not the column you specify there.

You can use `.set_index()` to create a df with a different index, and join with that.

```
df3 = df.join(df2.set_index('INDEX'), on = 'INDEX', how = 'left', lsuffix = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` instead of `join`:

```
>>> df.merge(df2, on='INDEX', how='left')

  THING  INDEX ITEM  INDEX_RAW
0     B      1    A          0
1     B      2    A          1
2     B      3    A          2
```